# sqlite with boolean values?

Tags: sqlite

i am getting some text and boolean values from server i need to save them in database.

this is my table . I defined boolean values as INTEGER couse in sqlite there is no boolean.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE outcomesStore(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , allowgo INTEGER,cod TEXT,youdidComments INTEGER, youwent INTEGER,ByDate INTEGER ," +
                "OnCompletion INTEGER,yourtext TEXT , yourGroup TEXT, yourConsultation INTEGER )");
```

and i am getitng these values from server.

```
Store[] Storedata = Configuration.getStore();


    booleanvalues[0] = Store[0].isallowgo ();
```

and inserting like this

```
 helperdatabase = new DatabaseHelperInurseBusiness(this);
            db = helperdatabase.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues insertOutcomes = new ContentValues();


            insertOutcomes.put(helperdatabase.ALLOW_GO,booleanvalues[0]);
        db.insert("outcomesStore", helperdatabase.ALLOW_GO,insertOutcomes);
```

Its not working even not giving any error.

Comment: Convert the `booleanvalues[0]` to numeric before insertion. 
try this:
insertOutcomes.put(helperdatabase.ALLOW_GO,1);

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i got the solution.

Thanks Yaqub Ahamad.

```
    insertOutcomes.put(DatabaseHelperInurseBusiness.ALLOW_GO,storedata.isAllowGo()== true ? 1:0);
```

Answer (score 27):

Actually, SQLite does support `BOOLEAN` type, but may be not exactly in the way you expect.

You can create column of `BOOLEAN` type using standard `CREATE TABLE`, and then populate it:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (name VARCHAR(10), flag BOOLEAN);
INSERT INTO mytable (name, flag) VALUES ('Alice', 0);
INSERT INTO mytable (name, flag) VALUES ('Bob',   1);
```

Then you can get your data back, and use standard `BOOLEAN` logic while doing so:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE flag
```

or using different `BOOLEAN` expressions:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE NOT flag
```

and so on. ([Obligatory SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/54ecd/1))

In other words, it all works great, the only catch is that you must use `0` instead of `FALSE` and `1` instead of `TRUE` (*this includes trying to set values from client software*). Note that this is somewhat similar to other SQL engines (For example, PostgreSQL supports using `'0'`/`'1'`, `'f'`/`'t'` and `false`/`true` for setting `FALSE`/`TRUE` values by client software).

Also, if you were to use this `BOOLEAN` field in numeric context (like adding or multiplying) it will behave as number 0 or 1, while in other SQL engines adding `BOOLEAN` and `INTEGER` may cause an exception because of incompatible types.